# auto click once in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, awtrobot

How can I make my program automatically do **mouse click** just only **once** each time after running a method on my JFrame?

can it be achieved by using robot class?

Comment: What outcomes are you trying to achieve by simulating a mouse click in the `JFrame`?  There might be better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but I think I speak for all in asking you to provide a lot more information about your problem domain, about your telling us more about the overall problem that you're trying to solve, and less about the specific way that you're trying to solve this. Do this, and I'll bet that we can help you progress pronto.

Comment: I take that back. Please improve your question.

Comment: *"can it be achieved by using robot class"* - But the question remains why?  The solution will depend greatly on the problem and what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Robot could possibly do this, but simply calling `doClick()` on your JButton should be good enough, unless you absolutely need the cursor over the button.

```
private void someMethod() {
    myButton.doClick();
}
```

Comment: sorry maybe I did not specify that is not a button but a mouse rather

Comment: @newbieinprogramming: sounds a bit sketchy, and smells of an [xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please better define your problem space, not how you're trying to solve it, as your approach may be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

The following will have the robot simply click in place, wherever it is when the method is run. I'm not sure if this is your intent, since the mouse may very well be anywhere on the screen at that moment. If it needs to be a mouse click, you can set position with `robot.mouseMove(int x, int y);`.

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    private void someMethod() {
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
```